# WebDriver: не срабатывает эмплицитное ожидание

Tags: c#, selenium

Написал вот такой метод Wait для ожидания элемента:

```
public static bool Wait(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 60)
        {

            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof (NoSuchElementException));
            return wait.Until(dr => dr.ElementIsPresent(by));

        }

public static bool ElementIsPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            try
            {
                return driver.FindElement(by).Displayed;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Вызываю его для несуществующего элемента на странице и почему-то сразу валюсь с ошибкой:

```
_driver.Wait(By.Id("some element"));
element: 'By.Id: some element' ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"some element"}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну так вам же пишет он - не могу найти элемент. И падает в By.id(....)

Comment: Вобще-то я предполагал, что метод будет ждать елемент 60 секунд и потом свалиться, а не сразу.

Comment: _driver.Wait(___________By.Id("some element")_______);

Оно у вас до вашего предположения даже не доходит

Comment: Вы давно занимаетесь WebDriver'ом? Просто ваши ответы показывают, что не представляете, о чем вообще речь.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть проблема именно в `return driver.FindElement(by).Displayed;`? Елемент не найден, но вы у него пытаетесь забрать Displayed